# Reasons for autowired beans in spring being null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, javabeans, autowired

I've come across a problem that at run time autowired beans in a certain class are all null. I would like an answer that will cover all possibilities on why a spring autowired bean is not initialised.

- Only java config is used, no xml files at all
- New keywords are only used at bean definitions
- All classes and fields are annotated appropriately

Eg:

```
@ComponentScan(...
@Configuration
public... 
    @Bean
    public ...  myBean(){
        return new ...;
    } 

@Service
public ... 
    @Autowired
    private ... myBean ;
```

And I guess this is when I am trying to use service;

```
@Configuration
public ...

    // Constructor    
    service = new Service();

    // Field
    private Service service;
```

Comment: The class that should have its fields autowired, are you sure you are creating it by asking Spring for an instance? Are you sure you aren't just calling `new MyClass()` and hoping it would have its fields autowired? Because they are only autowired when you get `MyClass` from the spring context.

Comment: @acdcjunior - hey I have edited the question is that the problem in creating service? cause I am calling new there??

Comment: Is `Service` annotated with `@Service`? Because if it is, when you call `new Service()`, the annotation `@Service` is completely ignored and the `@Autowired`s are as well, thus any field annotated with `@Autowired` will be null.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is object instance is not a spring bean  (the one which you want to inject something) in other words: Spring does not know the instance, and therefore does not care about it

*BTW: if Spring would know/take care of that instance and would not find a matching bean, then the default result for `@Autowired` is an exception*

Comment: Your *BTW*, exactly. If the object is not a bean, the exception is thrown, instead of `null` being autowired.

Comment: @acdcjunior: No the other way around: if the object IS A bean, then the exception is thrown, instead of null being autowired. (except you use `@Autowired(required=false)` )

Comment: By object I meant the dependency.

Comment: @acdcjunior: then it is right, of course, spring can only inject beans.